# Can we call handler in non-activity class in Android?

Tags: android

I am pretty new to `Android`, but having some issue on the `Handler`.

I have a *worker thread* which runs in the non-activity class. I would like the worker thread to handle some background tasks, while I also want to do other stuff on the non-activity class. However, the handler doesn't work at all. Is there any alternate solution? Here is how I implemented:

```
public class NonActivity {

    private WorkerThread mWorkerThread = null;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(){

        //why the message never come here?????
    }

    //constructor
    public NonActivity()
    {
        //call worker thread from non-activity class
        mWorkerThread = new WorkerThread();
    }
}
```

private class WorkerThread extends Thread {

```
    public void run() {

       //call sendMessageToMainThread
       sendMessageToMainThread();
    }

    private void sendMessageToMainThread() {
       mHandler.sendMessage(put message here);    
    }
}
```

Comment: use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead

Comment: You could create your handler with Main-Looper. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper%28%29 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Answer (score 0):

Handler needs a [looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) which runs the messages in thread the looper is attached to. By default, handler uses looper in the current thread but if the thread has no looper, you need to provide it explicit looper. You can use [the main looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper()) or create your own in a separate thread (see the example in looper's documentation).